# math1 problem ( last term final question)

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt x)$$
Hello everyone I pass 1st grade in ceng and  struggled with maths (calculus). My teacher  showed  us the final exams question since I didn't solve it. I haven't got a solution technique at the moment, so I would like help with this. Thank you everyone.

Comment: try putting in 1, then 2, then 100, etc.  See if that starts getting you somewhere.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math.StackExchange! Please provide more context to make your question appealing: what did you tried to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider your problem
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{x}\right]$$
what we can see is that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2-1}\approx\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x$$
so we can rewrite our problem as:
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[x-\sqrt{x}\right]$$
and since $\sqrt{x}<x$ for $x>1$ we can see that this limit is divergent towards $\infty$

Comment: can we  apply  l'hospital  laws in this  questiton ?

Comment: well it is not a fraction of functions like $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Comment: trash answer? what do you mean?